# How can I make a folder/partition on one computer appear as a mass storage device to another?

Tags: windows-7, usb, file-sharing

Is there anyway to make a folder or a partition on a computer (Linux or Windows) act like a mass storage device to other computers or devices when connected with a Male-Male USB cable?

For example, I have a Windows 7 computer with 2 partitions, `C` and `D`. I would then connect that computer to another computer or a Smart TV using a Male-Male USB cable, and the other computer or device recognizes a folder/partition on current computer as a mass storage device.

Is this possible?

If not, is there any USB switch that can connect an external hard drive or flash drive to both a computer and TV without the need to manually switch them? (I know about some USB switches, but they only support automatic switching with some certain types of printers, not with mass storage)

Comment: " For example, I have a windows 7 computer with 2 partitions c and d, then connect that computer to another computer or a smart TV using a USB cable (has to be male to male USB cable) then the other computer or TV recognizes the current computer as a usb device." **Please do not do this.  The Smart TV idea will not work so drop that.**

Comment: "or flash drive to both the computer and TV without the need to manually switch them (I know about some USB switches but they only support automatic switching with some certain types of printers, not with mass storage)" **There are dozens of routers on the market that support network devices.  Most Smart TVs and Mobile devices do not support them of course**

Comment: Ramhound, please condense your argument into an answer. Even if it's not what the OP is looking for, if you think it's helpful to convince them not to do something, that's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for (since it's not using USB, and it probably won't work with a Smart TV), but it could help if you're just looking for a way to share a drive between two computers

If the computers are connected to the same network you could share the drive over the network on the first computer, and then map that drive on the second computer to any drive letter you'd like. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-XM/windows7/How-do-I-share-the-root-of-a-drive and http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive should help you out :)

Even if they're not connected to the same network, you could create an ad-hoc network http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network and then share the drive.